# Fonts are not loaded in my React-Native project-Android

Tags: react-native, fonts, font-awesome

I think something went wrong when I reorganized my RN project in order to export APK. Here is the issue:

I'm using checkbox and some other icons from @expo//vector-icons in one of my components.

Everytime I launch it, I have a font which is missing. Feather, MaterialCommunityIcons,...
I face the same issue in my searchbar in an other component.

Checkboxes and icons look like [image: checkbox_error] after i Dismiss the error in my app

I'm really trying hard to fix it (for hours) and to import my font in some way or an another...

There is the beginning of my code if someone see what is wrong ... Thank you all !

> "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadAssetsAsync()
      }
    
    loadAssetsAsync = async () => {
        await Font.loadAsync({
        MaterialCommunityIcons,
          Feather: require('../assets/Fonts/Feather.ttf'),
          FontAwesome: require('../assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf'),
          'Material Icons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialIcons.ttf'),
          'MaterialIcons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialIcons.ttf'),
          'MaterialCommunityIcons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'),
          'Material-Community-Icons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'),
        })
      }
```

The fatal error

[image: Fatal_error]

A warning

[image: Warning_message]

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are loading async **AFTER** the component was mounted. So you need to wait for fonts before rendering your component's childs. So you can try somthing like

```
loadAssetsAsync = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
    MaterialCommunityIcons,
      Feather: require('../assets/Fonts/Feather.ttf'),
      FontAwesome: require('../assets/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf'),
      'Material Icons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialIcons.ttf'),
      'MaterialIcons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialIcons.ttf'),
      'MaterialCommunityIcons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'),
      'Material-Community-Icons': require('../assets/Fonts//MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'),
    })
    this.setState({fontsLoaded: true})
  }

  render(){
      if(this.state.fontsLoaded){
          return(
            // Your component
          )
      }
      else{
          return(
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
          )
      }
  }
```